# ¿Cómo realizar relaciones de tabla1 a tabla2 en donde tabla2 tiene dos llaves foráneas con el id de tabla1 en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo dos tablas en MYSQL, tabla1 que sería "usuarios", la cual almacena todos los usuarios de una aplicación y tabla2 que sería "tareas", la cual almacena las tareas que un usuario asigna a otro, entonces en la tabla "tareas" tengo dos campos los cuales definen el id del usuario que crea la tarea y el id del usuario de debe realizar dicha tarea, a continuación el diagrama:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento lo planteé así, pero no se si es la manera correcta de hacerlo, ya que existe una particularidad y es que mis dos campos foráneos de la tabla "tareas" hacen relación al mismo campo (id) de la tabla "usuarios", me pregunto si existe alguna manera que sea una sola relación pero con mis dos campos diferentes o de la manera en que lo hice es correcta.

Comment: Cada relación expresa una forma de relacionar atributos de tus entidades. No te enfrasques en optimizar o simplificar cosas antes de hacer que funcionen. Esa simplificación prematura suele llevar a problemas. PD. No es el escenario habitual pero no es incorrecto. Cada uno de esos campos id_xxx_yyy tiene que validarse contra los ID de usuario existentes y ya está.

Comment: Vale gracias por tu aporte.